# Tampermonkey/JS: Only run the script when the ENTIRE page is FULLY loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I created a simple script that auto pauses any video that autoplays. The code is simple:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button ytp-button")[0].click();
```

And if I run it in the Chrome dev console after the entire page loads, everything works.

However, if I run this in tampermonkey, I get the error of cannot do `.click()` of `undefined`, which basically means the script ran before that element loaded.

I have tried:

- `// @run-at       document-idle`
- `window.onload`
- `$(window).on('load', function(){})`
- `window.addEventListener('load', function () {})`
- `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){})`

But it just won't work. To test this, I put things in a `main()` function and did a `setTimeout(main,5000)`. If everything works as expected, then the video should be paused when it has played for 5 seconds. However, the video gets paused when it's only been 2 or 3 seconds depending on how fast the page loaded, meaning the script ran before everything had loaded. If I delete the `setTimeout`, then things don't work at all. Any solutions?

Comment: Use MutatioinObserver or [specific youtube events](/a/34100952/).